# CSS background not working in Chrome and FF

Tags: css

Hello I have next css class that working in IE fine but not working in FF and Chrome, what shold i change to fix it ?

```
.extHeaderStyle { background: transparent url(/sline/navigation/header/images/footerBack.gif) repeat-x -1 left; }


<tr class="GridHeaderStyle extHeaderStyle" align="left" style="font-size:14px;">
            <th scope="col">AppErrorId</th><th scope="col">AppName</th><th scope="col">ServerIp</th><th scope="col">ClientIp</th><th scope="col">Request</th><th scope="col">ErrMsg</th><th scope="col">CreatedBy</th><th scope="col">CreatedDate</th>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove -1? Or use a unit after the value.

Comment: I remove it but I don't see background

Comment: Give the link of the page where you're trying to fix it.

Comment: I can't do it. This is private site

Answer (score 1):

You need a unit after `-1`, e.g. `-1px` or `-1em`. Only the value `0` is allowed without a unit.

Answer (score 0):

I put classes to th tag and  background has start working.